# Badges, Answers, Questions, everything disappeared

Tags: support

I don't know why but suddenly my badges, answers, questions etc. all disappeared :\

I had more than 8 answers, 3 badges and everything disappeared. One second I was watching my profile and everything was there but the next when I did a refresh everything was gone except of my reputation. What happened?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that my votes also disappeared. everything shows 0 in my profile except of questions (this one) and tags ("support" in this question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're on meta, your profile shows only posts, badges and votes you made on meta.

If you click the "parent" link (and everything goes back to orange) and then go to your profile, you'll see that all your posts[1], badges and votes are still [there](https://askubuntu.com/users/2898).

[1] Or click the "parent user" link on your meta profile as moberley pointed out.

Comment: Also there is a "parent user" link below the reputation score and views counter on the meta user page. That link points directly to the profile page on the regular ("parent") site.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that!! where can I read about the difference between meta and parent? It might sound like a dumb question but I don't really get why there are two versions of the same site?

Comment: @Antonis askubuntu is for asking questions about ubuntu and meta for asking questions related to the site askubuntu.